# MS SQL SSIS - Use statement to Import flatfile

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, ssis

I am working on creating the following statement in SSIS
to bring in a Flatfile.

```
SELECT CASENUMBER, MAX(CHANGEDATE) ChangeDT
FROM   SRC_Flatfile
WHERE  ThisValue IS NULL
AND    ThatValue IN (40,41)
GROUP BY CASENUMBER
```

I am using the Aggregate Function, but there seems to be no 
option to correctly set up the query. I can `Group By` and 
choose maximum `ChangeDate`,  and not much else. Does anyone 
know how to convert this query into SSIS?  I am using 
**Visual Studio 2008**.

Maybe I am using the wrong tool.

Thank you!

Comment: A typical design pattern for this would be to import the flat file unchanged into a "staging" table, then use the SQL engine for set-based operations like GROUP BY to move the data into the permanent destination.

Comment: SSIS doesn't have a built-in way to do a SELECT from a flat-file.   You could write a custom script component to do it, I suppose.

Comment: Upon working to format "Custom Script", the process threw an error about the destination. I matched the data with the Destination, but the error persists.

Comment: You can import file into an object, sort, then iterate through to export to another file or load to db. This is one option to avoid doing this in the db.

Comment: Sort by CaseNumber, ChangeDate desc. That way if casenumber changes from one row to the next, either export or insert into destination.